# 5 V from 12 V at 650 W?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have 220V AC to 12V DC with 130Amps output. Could I convert this 12V DC to 5V DC where 130Amps not change?

Comment: You could...but *holy cow* -- even with a buck converter, you'd need 90+% efficiency to not be dissipating unholy amounts of power man...

Comment: This sounds like a question where knowing the application might help quite a bit. Could you please tell us what it is that you are using this power for? We might be able to detail a better approach than a single 5 volt, 130 amp output.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. There are several options:

1. Get a resistor and a giant heat sink, if your load is constant.
2. Get a Switiching regulator from 12V to 5V, at 650W, that's still going to need a heatsink.
3. Realise option 1 and 2 are more expensive and inferior to buying an off-to-shelf 230V to 5V power supply
4. Try to mess with your current power supplys regulator to get 5V out of it, and in the process get a nice feel what 230V through your body feels like (hint: it's not great)

Comment: Option 1 and 2 both have the same amount of power dissipation. Thus the _giant heat sink_ is required in both cases. However, NEVER do linear regulation in this power range!

Comment: I did say switching didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

130 amps!? What are you working with? That's industrial type of requirements.

At a 100℅ efficiency, Power out = Power in. If you step down the voltage by means of a very efficient DC DC converter, then the current has to go up, that's just the physical properties. Now you could set up a current limiter so that the current doesn't exceed a specific max.

Also, your load is what determines how much current it really needs. So even if a source can supply x amount of current, it doesn't mean it always pushes the max current to all loads.

Comment: That's only true, if it's a **voltage source**. In most cases we assume this, because current sources are very rare except in constant current (CC) LED applications.

Comment: Thousands of addressable ws2812 LEDs?

Comment: @soosaisteven maybe, who knows huh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* convert 12 V at up to 130 A to 5 V at 130 A.  But, at such a high power level (650 W), that should be a last resort at best.

You already have 220 V AC available to run the 12 V supply.  Get a 5 V supply that can also run from that 220 V AC.

Every time you convert electrical power from one voltage x current combination to another voltage x current combination, there is some loss due to the process not being 100% efficient.  At 650 W, even a 93% efficient converter will lose 49 W.  That's a lot of heat to get rid of.  The 12 V power supply certainly loses some power too, but dealing with the heat is already built into it.  Likewise, a 5 V power supply would also have this heat handling built in.

Converting from 220 V to 12 V, then converting again from 12 V to 5 V is going to waste more power, which means more heat to get rid of.  Also, while a 12 V to 5 V DC converter capable of 650 W is possible to make, this is not a beginner project.  For anyone that has to ask here, the answer is really "No, you can't".  Even if you did eventually get something to work that isn't dangerous to users and that doesn't regularly blow up parts, the result will have cost significantly more than a off the shelf power supply.

The relatively high cost of a 220 V AC to 5 V DC 650 W supply should tell you that this is not a simple problem.  Even finding such  supply won't be easy.  One possibility is to look around where electro-plating equipment is sold.  Electro-plating requires such low voltages at high currents.